# Laravel: Extend models from a second Laravel application

Tags: php, rest, laravel, eloquent

I wrote a REST API with Laravel. On top of that i want to create an admin panel with a lot of statistics and "mighty" moderation tools which should render on server-side.
While the REST API uses OAuth2.0 and only returns JSON+HAL (HATEOAS), the admin panel would use a HTTP Basic auth plus a normal credential login with session based authentication.

I know it would be easily possible to use a second auth-filter and Route groups to make all this happening in one application. And i know that libs are only loaded if needed. But i want to create a second application which is completely independent.

Why?
To keep the REST API lightweight: No unnecessary libraries, no second auth-layer, no additional routes, rules and filters, etc. The REST API is Restful and i do not want to add additional clutter. Though it might make testing a little bit more complicated.

Here is how it should look like:

**backend**

- rest (Laravel application 1)

-- app

--- models

---- RestapiModel.php

- admin (Laravel application 2)

-- app

--- models

---- AdminModel.php

The problem is: In application 2 i need to work with models of application 1
So i would like to do s.th. like

```
class AdminModel extends RestapiModel {

     protected $connection = 'application_1_database';

     // Statistical methods
     // Database manipulation
     // etc.
}
```

I now have two questions:

1. How can i make this possible? "AdminModel extends RestapiModel" won't work. Do i have to use namespaces, traits or just include the Model on top of the file? How would you solve this?
2. What do you think about the complete approach to separate API and administration?

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: Couldnt the admin section just interact with the API as well? Then you have one 'interface' to your application...

Comment: This would also add a lot of clutter to the controllers as i'd have to add a permission or role layer to the controllers as admins have more rights and possibilities than normal clients. Of course, for some normal methods it would work. But it would also make it harder to distinguish between admin functions and "normal" functions. But to be honest i simply don't like to have administrational functions and client-functions at the same place. Just a gut feeling it will make models as well as controllers really big.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but you can use `require` to import the file(s)

```
require base_path().`/../rest/models/RestapiModel.php`;

class AdminModel extends RestapiModel {

    protected $connection = 'application_1_database';

    // Statistical methods
    // Database manipulation
    // etc.
}
```

Or you can autload all the models of the rest api using composer. Your `composer.json` in the admin application could look like this:

```
// ...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "../../rest/app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        // ...
    ]
},
// ...
```

(After changing the autoload section make sure to run `composer dump-autoload`)